# add icon to j2me application

Tags: java-me

How can I add icon for my j2me application midlet? I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MIDlet description file (*MANIFEST.MF*) change/add such lines:

```
MIDlet-1: YourMidletName,icon.png,MainClass
MIDlet-Icon: icon.png
```

Answer (score 5):

If You are using the netbeans for developing j2me.Then follow this step:-

Custmoization--->Application Description--->click Midlet Tab--->Select the midlet and click on edit button---->then select the Midlet icon which u want to use.Select ok--->execute it in phone

Answer (score 0):

```
MIDlet-Name: MIDgetSuite
MIDlet-Vendor: Vendor, Inc.
MIDlet-Version: 0.1.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 2245
MIDlet-Jar-URL: MIDgetSuite.jar
MIDlet-1: MIDget,/icons/icon.png,MainEngine
```

Please refer this http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Adding_an_icon_to_a_MIDlet